# For loop to run through values

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a for loop to run through values, but I am not sure of how to do this correctly.

```
        string[] GoogleID = { "ga:1381000", "ga:1860066"};

        // Loop with the foreach keyword.

        foreach (string value in GoogleID)
            {


            if (GoogleID.ToString() == "ga:1381000")
            {
                WebName = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                WebName = "No";
            }


            }
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I make it check both values?

It says my string for GoogleID.ToString  = String[]

Comment: Try changing if (GoogleID.ToString() == "ga:1381000") to if (value == "ga:1381000" || value == "ga:1860066")

Comment: if (GoogleID.ToString() == "ga:1381000") - You don't want to use GoogleID on this line. You want to do if (value == "ga:1381000"). You are looping over everything 'item' in your list called GoogleID, your foreach has created a variable called 'value' to represent each item in that list.

Comment: I think he wants to check if the collection contains a specific item.

Comment: You are checking every value in the string array, and every time you set the same variable: at the end, `WebName` will depend only on the last element of the array . Stop looping as soon as you find the value you are looking for- (or use LINQ `Any`, as @w.b. suggested)

Answer (score 7):

You would want to do it like this.

```
string[] GoogleID = { "ga:1381000", "ga:1860066"};

        // Loop with the foreach keyword.

        foreach (string value in GoogleID)
            {


            if (value  == "ga:1381000")
            {
                WebName = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                WebName = "No";
            }


            }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ:

```
WebName = GoogleId.Any(s => s == "ga:1381000") ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should correct your code as shown in the following sample code snippet:

```
    string[] GoogleID = { "ga:1381000", "ga:1860066" };
    string WebName;

    // Loop with the foreach keyword.
    foreach (string _val in GoogleID)
    {
        WebName = (_val == "ga:1381000") ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
```

For better performance you may use the following code snippet:

```
    string[] GoogleID = { "ga:1381000", "ga:1860066" };
    string WebName;

    // Loop with the for keyword.
    for (int i = 0; i < GoogleID.Length; i++ )
    {
        WebName = (GoogleID[i] == "ga:1381000")? "Yes":"No";
    }
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another LINQ suggestion.

```
WebName = GoogleID.Contains("ga:1381000") ? "Yes" : "No"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop as shown below:-

```
 string[] GoogleID = { "ga:1381000", "ga:1860066" };
          //use for loop
          for (int i = 0; i < GoogleID.Length; i++)
         {
           if (GoogleID[i].ToString() == "ga:1381000")  //use index here 
            {
                WebName = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                WebName = "No";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

var WebName = GoogleID.Contains("ga:1381000") ? "Yes" : "No"

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop it was checking against first element in your group (GoogleID or GoogleID[0]). Thus always true and always printing "yes"
It should be checking against "value".  See the minor changes below. I changed "value" to X to highlight it.

string WebName;

```
    string[] GoogleID = { "ga:1381000", "ga:1860066"};

    // Loop with the foreach keyword.

    foreach (var X in GoogleID)
        {
            if (X == "ga:1381000")
            {
                WebName = "Yes";
            }

            else
            {
                WebName = "No";
            }
        }
```

Fully functioning version here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lihDeY